# PHP form variables not getting passed to the URL

Tags: php, html

I am not sure where I am wrong here. I am doing it like I always used to do but the form variables are not getting passed to the URL.

My code is below:

```
<form id="update_submit" name="update_submit" method="post" action="profile_update.php" >
    <h3 class="ghj" style="color:white">
        <input style="background:rgba(0,0,0,0);border:2px solid #D8D8D8;color:white;" type="text" id="name1" name="name1" value="<?php echo $fullname_1; ?>" required /> | 
        <input style="background:rgba(0,0,0,0);border:2px solid #D8D8D8;color:white" type="text" id="city" name="city" value="<?php echo $city_1; ?>" required />
    </h3>
    <div class="bs-example">
        <table class="table">
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td style="color:white">
                        <h1 style="color:white;font-size:150%" class="head"  id="h1.-bootstrap-heading">
                            <span style="background-color: black;"> 
                                <input style="width:400px;background: grey;border: 2px solid #D8D8D8;color:grey" type="text" id="email" name="email" value="<?php echo $email_1; ?>" required disabled />
                            </span>
                        </h1>
                        <span style="background-color: black;">
                            Phone : <input style="background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);border: 2px solid  #D8D8D8;color:white" type="text" id="phone" name="phone" value="<?php echo  $phone_1; ?>" required />
                        </span>
                    </td>
                    <td class="type-info"></td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="submit-btn">
    <input type="submit" value="Update" style="background-color:   #585858;color:white">
</div>
</form>
```

Any help will be highly useful.

Comment: What is the expected behavior? And what do you mean with 'getting passed to the URL'?

Comment: when I press the submit button...then the url should be redirected to profile_update.php  like this /mysite.com/if/profile_update.php

Comment: So you don't want to _pass the variables to the URL_, but to your script (`profile_update.php`) without adding them to the URL

Comment: @Deva Well yeah, your variables will be posted over http to profile_update.php, but what are you getting there in `$_POST`?

Comment: @Bastiaan : didn't understand your question..... I am not getting anything in $_POST...but I change the method to get and it worked :) ....thanks a ton everyone for the support

Comment: Maybe the problem is in your `profile_update.php` script, post the corresponding code so that we can see whether there is a problem in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need get method, edit form to:

```
 <form id="update_submit" name="update_submit" method="get" action="profile_update.php" >
```

Get method puts variables in url, post method put variables in http headers.

Comment: get method puts variables in url, post method put variables in http headers.

Answer (score 0):

Pay attention to the disable attribute on the input email, this value will not be posted. Maybe you should use readonly instead.

Comment: @Deva yes, i tested your form on my local server and they pass.

Comment: Do you have javascript that do something before submit?

Answer (score 0):

You have to change the method of how to send the form. You got several options, GET and POST.

---

- **get**  *Default. Appends the form-data to the URL in name/value pairs: URL?name=value&name=value*
- **post**     *Sends the form-data as an HTTP post transaction*

Be aware of this.

So to use GET change `method` to `GET`.

Example:
`<form id="update_submit" name="update_submit" method="GET" action="profile_update.php">`